# How do I handle 196,608 if statements in c?

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm trying to implement a C program with 65,536*3 `if` statements such as included below. I'm on Visual Studio 2013. The problem is that the build never finishes. I know there are very many `if` statements, so is there any way to resolve this kind of problem?

```
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 0))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    2;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 1))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    12;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 2))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    100;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 3))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    20;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 4))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    0;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 5))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    30;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 6))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    0;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 7))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    40;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 8))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    0;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 9))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    120;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 10))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    3;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 11))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    4;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 12))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    7;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 13))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    3;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 14))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    5;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 15))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    30;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 16))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    0;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 17))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    0;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 18))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    1;
if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 19))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    0;
...

if ((  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 255) && ( bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 255))  data[i*rwsize + j] =    25;
```

Comment: Looks like you want a lookup-table

Comment: @tkausl yes right

Comment: There are so many redundant `data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0` checks in your code. Just do it once with a lookup table or switch

Comment: You could always nest your `ifs`.  Select out the first common `if (  pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0)` and follow up with the underlying `if` thereafter.

Comment: @Rishav Thanks, but If you let me know with any example code, then I'll do understand better then this.

Comment: You say there are 180,000 if statements, but if they all fit the pattern established by the first few that you've shown, there should be "only" 65,536 if statements.  Which is it?  If it's 180,000, please show some of the statements that don't fit the pattern as well.

Comment: @zwol yes right,  exact number is 65,536*3 because each R,G,B have different data.

Comment: Use a 256*256 array as a lookup table and this becomes one line of code without any `if`s.

Comment: If you cannot do away with redundant checks, using a loop and array might help.

Comment: @interjay Would you please let me know little bit more?

Comment: @star01 I left an detailed explained example in the answers. Pls check.

Comment: That depends on the actual data. There is hardly ever a reason for such a bunch of seperate `if`s. Try to find an algorithm to calculate the values, etc. Anyway, this is too broad for SO.

Comment: Incidentally, the build never completes probably because the compiler is trying to figure out which of the if statements' conditions are mutually exclusive, which involves comparing every condition to every other condition, which takes time proportional to the _square_ of the number of if statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `if`s at all, what you're looking for is a plain old lookup table.

```
unsigned char table[] = {2, 12, 100, 20, 0, 30, ...};

data[i*rwsize + j] = table[pre_data[i*rwsize + j] * 256 + bdata[i*rwsize + (j)]];
```

Or with a two-dimensional array

```
unsigned char table[256][256] = {
  {2, 12, 100, 20, 0, 30, ...},
  {...},
  ...
};

data[i*rwsize + j] = table[pre_data[i*rwsize + j]][bdata[i*rwsize + (j)]];
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a condition for every possible combination of values of two variables that range from 0 to 255, and the code for each condition just assigns a constant to a third variable.  That can be implemented with a two-dimensional look-up table.

```
static const uint8_t data_for_pre_and_b[256][256] = {
  { 2, 12, 100, 20, 0, 20, 0, 30, ... },
  ...
}

size_t pixel = i * rwsize + j;
data[pixel] = data_for_pre_and_b[pre_data[pixel]][bdata[pixel]];
```

I've also manually eliminated the common subexpression `i * rwsize + j` to reduce the chance of typos and make it easier to read.

It sounds like for your actual problem you will need three of these tables.  In addition to being both faster to compile and faster to run, this is better because it makes it much easier to change the tables.  You could even read them out of a file.

If there are any exceptions to the pattern -- maybe in a tiny handful of the 65,536 cases you need to do some extra math -- the thing to do is designate a special value in the table to mean "this is an exception".

```
data[pixel] = data_for_pre_and_b[pre_data[pixel]][bdata[pixel]];
if (data[pixel] == 255)
    data[pixel] = exceptional_calculation(pre_data[pixel], bdata[pixel]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Now since I see that the variables that gain the values are the same and for different values of `bdata` you **must** use `else if` instead of just `if`. This will skip the checking of other `if` conditions in the program. Beware that `else if` is not always important as sometimes the logic requires `else` to be absent but that is not the case with your code.

I have also shown how you can nest the `pre_data` variables and skip re-checking if `pre_data` is say 0 if you already know that it is 0.

```
if (pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 0){      //All the bdata part is to be checked only if this is to be true. This way you avoid rechecking if pre_data is 0
        if (bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 0)
            data[i*rwsize + j] =    2;
        else if(bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 1)
            data[i*rwsize + j] =    12;
        ...
        ...
        else if(bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 255)
            data[i*rwsize + j] =    3333;
}

else if (pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 1){   //this else make sures you dont have to check this condition if earlier conditoin is met since all your values are unique and the setting variable is also uniquely defined accordingly
    if (bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 0)
        data[i*rwsize + j] =    2;
    else if(bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 1)
        data[i*rwsize + j] =    12;
    ...
    ...
    else if(bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 255)
        data[i*rwsize + j] =    3333;
}
...
...
...
...
else if(pre_data[i*rwsize + j]  == 255){
    if (bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 0)
        data[i*rwsize + j] =    2;
    else if(bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 1)
        data[i*rwsize + j] =    12;
    ...
    ...
    else if(bdata[i*rwsize + (j)] == 255)
        data[i*rwsize + j] =    3333;
}
```